# using ajax how to show the values in particular td without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using inline edit to edit the td and and after editing i am doing some calculation with edited value and i displaying that calculated value in particular td without refreshing the page,my problem is if i am doing two calculation with edited value and i want to show both the calculated value in different td but i can't show because  now its showing last the calculated value in the both the td. i want to show the calculated values in different td can anyone guide me how to do it

**java script:**

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){               
        $('td.edit').click(function(e){                              

                                                    success: function(data){
                                                        $('#CPH_GridView1_supplier_total_cost'+arr[2]).empty();
                                                        $('#CPH_GridView1_supplier_total_cost'+arr[2]).append(data);
                                                        $('#clienttotalprice'+arr[2]).empty();
                                                        $('#clienttotalprice'+arr[2]).append(data);
                                                         $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                                                         $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                                                    }});                                         }                                    
                                  }
                         );



    });
</script>
```

**html**

```
<td id="CPH_GridView1_supplier_total_cost'.$rows['id'].'" style="width:182px" class="edit supplier_total_cost '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["supplier_total_cost"].'</td>
<td id="clienttotalprice'.$rows['id'].'" style="width:217px" class="edit clienttotalprice '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["clienttotalprice"].'</td>
```

**updatedetailed.php**

```
<?php
        print $suppliertotalcost;
        print $clienttotalprice;



?>
```

Comment: Please try to localize the code which causes the problem. Most of the code you posted seems rather not relevant.

Comment: Please see the localized code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using print statement two times, and when this is returned to AJAX call, it's seen as one data.

Instead do it this way. At the end of `updatedetailed.php`:

```
$result=array();
$result['suppliertotalcost']=$suppliertotalcost;
$result['clienttotalprice']=$clienttotalprice;
echo json_encode($result);
```

And in your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({    type: "POST",
            url:"updatedetailed.php",
            data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&rowid="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1],
            success: function(res){
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(res); //added line
                $('#CPH_GridView1_supplier_total_cost'+arr[2]).empty();
                $('#CPH_GridView1_supplier_total_cost'+arr[2]).append(data.suppliertotalcost); //changed
                $('#clienttotalprice'+arr[2]).empty();
                $('#clienttotalprice'+arr[2]).append(data.clienttotalprice); //changed
                 $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                 $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
            }});
```